# How to dynamically create installable triggers as other users in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

So I have a Google Form-bound script that creates an installable trigger every time the Form is submitted. Now, I shared both the Form and the script to the actual users. At some point I have noticed that new triggers are not being created because quota limit is already reached. As I reviewed the list of installed triggers, I noticed that all of them are installed as "Me". How do I do it so that the other users who actually submitted the form (and created the installable trigger in the process) are identified as the "Owner" of the trigger and not me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code looks something like this:

```
function createOnFormSubmitTrigger() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('[FORM-ID]');
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('createTrigger')
  .forForm(form)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}

function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction2")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(10)
  .create();
}

function myFunction2 () {
  console.log('test')
}
```

And you're the one running the `createOnFormSubmitTrigger` function and granting the permissions, the trigger will be created for your account (installed as "me"). You would need to ask each user to run the `createOnFormSubmitTrigger` function by themselves in order to grant the permissions and get the trigger installed under their account. Which in this case wouldn't make much sense because each user trigger would be run each time a form submission is made no matter who submitted it.

As stated in the documentation for [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions):

> Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who
>   created them. For example, if you create an installable open trigger,
>   it runs when your colleague opens the document (if your colleague has
>   edit access), but it runs as your account. This means that if you
>   create a trigger to send an email when a document is opened, the email
>   is always be sent from your account, not necessarily the account that
>   opened the document. However, you could create an installable trigger
>   for each account, which would result in one email sent from each
>   account.

#### EDIT

You could try a workaround for your use-case by using [getActiveUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser) method which would return the trigger owner user and compare it to the user who submitted the form, which you can get with [getRespondentEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response?hl=en#getrespondentemail) method, using an `if` statement to compare both user's emails and run the code you need depending on that. This way the triggers will be run every time but the necessary code would be run only when the trigger owner is the same as the form respondent.

Comment: I tried to recreate your answer to observe what you said firsthand, and yes installing the trigger under each of their accounts would actually make the script run on each user trigger thereby producing multiple results when it's supposed to just run once.


So does this mean that what i wanted in the first place is not feasible? I've been scouring the Google Apps Script documentation for any possible leads but seems like this is really a design limitation.

Comment: Yes, it's unfeasible, because onFormSubmit trigger is intended to run for any form submission. I've edited my question with a possible workaround you could try.

Comment: The workaround you proposed actually worked in my case.