# How to make onEdit scripts that can set values in protected range, so that I can share my spreadsheet with other users?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm writing a simple onEdit scripts to set time on column A, when users modify a specific column. It works just fine, if I share the spreadsheet with edit permission. However, I don't want the users to edit the recorded time on Column A.

Thus, I protect the time recording range in column A. The onEdit function doesn't work for users only have view permission on the protected Range. It will be a great help, if anyone can provide a guide how to make the onEdit function set value on protected range for users with view permission. I've read some article on using Oath2.0, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

I post the code below for your reference:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet_name = s.getSheetName();
  var added_date = new Date()
  var added_time = Utilities.formatDate(added_date, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm a")
  if (sheet_name == "Monday" || sheet_name == "Tuesday" || sheet_name == "Wednesday" || sheet_name == "Thursday"
      || sheet_name == "Friday" || sheet_name == "Saturday" || sheet_name == "Sunday") {
    rng = s.getRange("B7:B100");
    var edit_row = e.range.getRow();
    var edit_col = e.range.getColumn();
    if (edit_col == rng.getColumn() && edit_row >= rng.getRow() && edit_row <= rng.getLastRow()) {
      s.getRange(edit_row, edit_col - 1).setValue(added_time);
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
   
  }
}
```

Comment: If you’re doing anything that requires permissions then your onEdit trigger should be installable. Also you should exam the event object because using it can greatly speed up your function

Comment: Can you please confirm that @Cooper commment works for you?

Comment: I don't know how to make the onEdit installable. I'm still figuring it out. I want the script always stay with the spreadsheet, so that if someone makes a copy of the spreadsheet, the script still works.

Comment: I've tried deploying a standalone function that set time value in the protected range as webapp and  call it in the onEdit, but it still doesn't work when I share the file.

Comment: Take a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61356994/how-to-dynamically-create-installable-triggers-as-other-users-in-google-apps-scr) post which is a very similar approach, you can create a installable trigger manually or programatically as the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) says. However, since you share your spreadsheet, that user can edit your spreadsheet script, no matter the triggers added. You can take a different approach by sending a notification every change on your Spreadsheet and verifying the user